# Can't pass state array values to DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm fetching data with `componentDidMount()` inside a React component, and storing that data inside `this.state`.

I can't seem to get the data from the state array into the DOM.

Here's the component:

```
class ArticlePrimaryContainer extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            article: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/articles/0')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(article => this.setState({article}, () => console.log('Article fetched..', article)));
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="article-primary-container">
                <div className="article-primary-container-image"></div>
                <div className="article-primary-container-content">
                        <h2 className="article-primary-container-heading">{this.state.article.title}</h2>
                        <p className="article-primary-container-paragraph">{this.state.article.content}</p>
                    </div>
                <div className="article-primary-container-content-overlay"></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I'm pulling this data from an express `index.js` file:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/articles/0', (req, res) => {
    const article = [
        { title: 'Article Title', content: 'Content for article 1.' },
    ];

    res.json(article);
});

const port = 5000;

app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);
```

In the component, I'm trying to pull these values from `state` with something like:

```
<h2 className="article-primary-container-heading">{this.state.article.title}</h2>
```

This isn't working. When I check the `React` tab in the browser console, the state array looks like this:

```
State
  article: Array[1]
    0: {…}
      content: "Content for article 1."
      title: "Article Title"
```

I'm not sure where that `0` is coming from exactly.

When I try `this.state.article.0.title` I get an error.

Comment: As far as I can see your code is mostly correct. Maybe take a look at [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) in JavaScript since you are using one for your `articles`. If you still have a [specific, reproducible problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) update your question accordingly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first.   you can only access an element in an array by bracket notation so it would be this.state.article[0].title

second.  typically if you have an array in react you would use Array.map to turn your array into an array of JSX objects,  and wrap that in curly braces.  I will provide an example below based on your code.  this allows you to grab ALL the blog posts, and lay them out in a repeatable way. - if you don't want/need to access all the blogposts,  then i suggest using `.then(article => this.setState({article: article[0]}));` and ditch the array altogether.

third,  you'll notice that the API call is happening in componentDidMount,  which means that the component will try to access the state object BEFORE the API call has returned and setState has run.  so you need to put any code that uses that bit of state behind a conditional to prevent an error.  you can use `if(state.article[0])`,  or a check on length,  in react, it's common to use the double-ampersand to do this, as I have done below.

```
class ArticlePrimaryContainer extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            article: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/articles/0')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(article => this.setState({article}, () => console.log('Article fetched..', article)));
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="article-primary-container">
                <div className="article-primary-container-image"></div>
                {this.state.article.length >= 1 && this.state.article.map((item)=>{
                    return(
                        <div>
                            <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                            <p>{item.content}</p>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
                <div className="article-primary-container-content-overlay"></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep checking this answer out and will mark it right if I can figure it out. I tried `this.setState({article[0]}));` and it's saying `Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected , `

Comment: `this.setState({article:0}));` seems to be okay, not sure if that is syntactically correct

Comment: sorry,  correction,  you want `this.setState({article: article[0]})`

Comment: nice, that was it. thanks. still trying to wrap my head around this. I imagine I'll be coming back to this answer repeatedly in the next few days.